# Tornado background task using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tornado, cx-oracle

I'm runnning a [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) server, using the underlying [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) framework.

I need the server to refresh some data at some point. This is done by fetching rows from an Oracle DB, using [Cx_Oracle](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Thanks to Tornado's [PeriodicCallback](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback), the program checks every 30 seconds if new data should be loaded:

```
server.start() 
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
pcallback = PeriodicCallback(db_obj.reload_data_async, 10 * 1e3)
pcallback.start()
server.io_loop.start()
```

Where `db_obj` is an instance of a class which takes care of the DB related functions (connect, fetch, ...).

Basically, this is how the `reload_data_async` function looks like:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

# methods of the db_obj class ...

@gen.coroutine
def reload_data_async(self):
  # ... first, some code to check if the data should be reloaded ...
  # ...
  if data_should_be_reloaded:
    new_data = yield executor.submit(self.fetch_data)

def fetch_data(self):
   """ fetch new data in the DB """
   cursor = cx.Cursor(self.db_connection) 
   cursor.execute("some SQL select request that takes time (select * from ...)")

   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   # some more processing thereafter 
   # ...
```

Basically, this works. But when I try to read the data while it's being load in `fetch_data` (by clicking for display in the GUI), the program crashes due to race condition (I guess?): it's accessing the data while it's being fetched at the same time.

I just discovered that [tornado.concurrent.futures](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch4.4/concurrent.html#tornado-concurrent-work-with-threads-and-futures) are not thread-safe:

> tornado.concurrent.Future is similar to concurrent.futures.Future, but
>   not thread-safe (and therefore faster for use with single-threaded
>   event loops).

All in all, I think I should create a new thread to take care of the CX_Oracle operations. Can I do that using Tornado and keep using the `PerodicCallback` function? How can I convert my asynchronous operation to be thread-safe? What's the way to do this?

**PS: Im using Python 2.7**

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to read? Let's say you store the fetched data in a list(or something else, whatever), and then you try to read this list in another thread(main thread). I don't think this will cause crash.

Comment: @Sraw well it crashes during `fetchall` and its reproducible 100% of the time. Basically, i'm doing a `select * from ...` so I try to read a bunch or rows which columns are numbers & strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

@Sraw is right: it should not cause crash.

**Explanation**: `fetch_data()` is using a cx Oracle [Connection](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.Connection) object (`self.db_connection`), which is NOT thread-safe by default. Setting the `threaded` parameter to `True` wraps the shared connection with a mutex, as described in Cx Oracle documentation:

> The threaded parameter is expected to be a boolean expression which
>   indicates whether or not Oracle should wrap accesses to connections
>   with a mutex. Doing so in single threaded applications imposes a
>   performance penalty of about 10-15% which is why the default is False.

So I in my code, I just modified the following and it now works without crashing when the user tries to access data while it's being refreshed:

```
# inside the connect method of the db_obj class
self.db_connection = cx.connect('connection string', threaded=True) # False by default
```